# How to implement press back twice to exit to ALL activities

Tags: java, android

I have implemented press back twice to exit an activity. But the problem is i have to copy and paste the same code in every activity to make it work for every activity.
I can't make a common class and put my implementation because activities already extends AppCompatActivity, and as per i know; multiple inheritance is not supported.
So how do i do this

This is my implementation, suggestions are welcome.

```
boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
        super.onBackPressed();
        return;
    }

    this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
    Toast.makeText(this, "Please click BACK again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            doubleBackToExitPressedOnce=false;
        }
    }, 2000);
}
```

Comment: THere's a difference between multiple inheretance and chained inheritance.  X extends Foo, Bar is illiegal.  X extends Foo, and Foo extends Bar is legal and common.

Comment: That said-  I recommend HIGHLY against doing this.  Its not what people expect, and will be confusing and REALLY annoying.  You'll just get a ton of bug reports and people deciding not to use your app over it.  Even at the root activity its annoying when someone decides to do this, at every activity it would be maddening.

Comment: Yes, i also don't think so that chain inheritance can be the right option to go with. it is getting more complex if i try to implement it in shared class. i don't know what to do with this and super keyword, any alternate solution will be very helpful. i am totally messed up with this thing.

Comment: Chained inheritance is the way to go, and if you have trouble with it you SERIOUSLY need to take the time to understand it.  Its extremely common.  But super in a chain always goes to the immediate parent of that class.

Comment: You're actually already using it.  AppCompatActivity?  It extends FragmentActivity.  FragmentActivity extends Activity.  Activity?  It extends Context.  Context?  It (like all Java objects without an explicit parent) extends Object.

Comment: Okay. i got it, but the implementation is using this and super keyword, if i put this in a separate class, this and super keyword will not work anymore. even i will not be able to call non-static method as i have to make the method static. so how can i reference the activity, i think i have to "queue" this task now.

Comment: No, the super keyword won't work in another class.  Of course you don't actually need the super keyword to do this.  I really think you need to put a pause on things and understand inheritance and object oriented programming in Java.  You're only going to come to more of these very simple questions that you don't understand the answer to until you understand that.

Comment: Yes, perhaps i do. I have referenced every available resources to me. But i am just a high school student. i am not a professional, that's why i asked this silly question, maybe. but it IS complex to me, i was wondering to do something more than the books teach us. that's why i came here, so please if you could provide me with any link or example, it would be very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make your own custom `Activity` that extends `AppCompatActivity` and put your implementation in there and then let each of your other activities extend that custom `Activity` instead of `AppCompatActivity`. this is not multiple inheritence

Answer (score 0):

Create your own custom (BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity) and put your OnBackPressed() implementation in BaseActivity and then extend all activities from BaseActivity.

Answer (score 0):

Don't listen to people telling you to create a static method. Instead, create a custom Activity class and make all of your classes extend that class. In that class put your custom onBackPressed functionality.

Another option is to go single activity with multiple fragments where you only need the back press implementation in one place.

Answer (score -1):

First override back click listener:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

remove the super.onBackPressed();

add this code:

```
private static final int MIN_TIME_INTERVAL_BETWEEN_BACK_CLICKS = 2000; // # milliseconds, desired time passed between two back presses.
private long backPressedTime;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (backPressedTime + MIN_TIME_INTERVAL_BETWEEN_BACK_CLICKS > System.currentTimeMillis()) {
        finishAffinity();
        return;
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Tap back button in order to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    backPressedTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man. it is working in activity's class file. but not in the shared method in which i am intending to put it to make it public, it throw error at this keyword, which is used for Toast, Thanks for help

Comment: Just replace the word 'this' in:
        Toast.makeText(this, "Tap back button in order to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
with getBaseContext() or getActivity() - if you use fragment.

if this not help you, i can send you an example how to implement Toast without context (this).